# How to compare and filter objects of array based on property value?

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure:

```
persons: [
  { name: 'Joe',  age: 20 },
  { name: 'Alex', age: 24 },  
  { name: 'Joe',  age: 34 },  
  { name: 'Bob',  age: 19 },  
  { name: 'Alex', age: 56 },
]
```

I want to get the oldest person-object for each existing name. So the result of this example would be:

```
filteredPersons: [
  { name: 'Joe',  age: 34 },  
  { name: 'Bob',  age: 19 },  
  { name: 'Alex', age: 56 },
]
```

How can I achieve this? Note that the number of different names is not fixed.

Comment: Did you want only 3 items of them thats are highest of age on the object?

Comment: @VinceSanchezTañan I want as many items as there are names

Comment: I have the solution to that using array(it can be readable) but it is sorted from highest.

Comment: are you ok with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect older ages for same names.

This soultion feature a function which compares two objects (or one object and a possible `undefined`) and if truthy and `b.age` is greater then `a.age`, it returns `b`, otherwise `a`.

At the end, only the values of the map are taken as result set.

```js
const
    older = (a, b) => b?.age > a.age ? b : a,
    persons = [{ name: 'Joe', age: 20 }, { name: 'Alex', age: 24 }, { name: 'Joe', age: 34 }, { name: 'Bob', age: 19 }, { name: 'Alex', age: 56 }],
    result = Array.from(persons.reduce((m, o) => m.set(
        o.name, 
        older(o, m.get(o.name))
    ), new Map).values());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

To do that in a single pass, you may employ [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) building up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) that will have `name` as a key and store maximum `age` together with `name` as a value-object.

Once the `Map` is ready, you may extract its values with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```js
const src = [{name:'Joe',age:20},{name:'Alex',age:24},{name:'Joe',age:34},{name:'Bob',age:19},{name:'Alex',age:56},],

    result = [...src
      .reduce((acc, {name, age}) => {
        const match = acc.get(name)
        match  ?
        match.age = Math.max(age, match.age) :
        acc.set(name, {name,age})
        return acc
      }, new Map)
      .values()
    ]
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: I ended up using a combination of your and Nina's answer but I unfortunately had to decide which one to accept. Thank you very much anyway

Comment: @leonheess :  Thre's, actually, nothing to *combine* since they are almost identical, (except for mine is a bit [faster](https://jsbench.me/lgkfcezwle/1) due to couple of tricks), however, if you find the other answer more comprehensive, you're absolutely free to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `reduce` the array and for each person in the array, check if the item has been encountered before, if so keep the oldest one, otherwise just keep the current object:

```
let results = persons.reduce((acc, person) => {                 // for each person in persons
  if(!acc[person.name] || acc[person.name].age < person.age) {  // if this person has never been encountered before (acc[person.name]) or if the already encountered one is younger (acc[person.name].age < person.age)
    acc[person.name] = person;                                  // store the current person under the name
  }
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));                                        // Object.create(null) instead of {} to create a prototypeless object
```

This will return an object containing the oldest persons in this format `{ name: person, name: person, ... }`. If you want to get them as an array, call `Object.values` like so:

```
let arrayResults = Object.values(results);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let persons = [{ name: 'Joe', age: 20 }, { name: 'Alex', age: 24 }, { name: 'Joe', age: 34 }, { name: 'Bob', age: 19 }, { name: 'Alex', age: 56 }];

let results = persons.reduce((acc, person) => {
  if(!acc[person.name] || acc[person.name].age < person.age) {
    acc[person.name] = person;
  }
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

let arrayResults = Object.values(results);

console.log("results:", results);
console.log("arrayResults:", arrayResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is more understandable for you.

```js
const persons = [
  { name: 'Joe',  age: 20 },
  { name: 'Alex', age: 24 },  
  { name: 'Joe',  age: 34 },  
  { name: 'Bob',  age: 19 },  
  { name: 'Alex', age: 56 },
]

let personsObj = {}, mxPersons = []

persons.forEach(person => {
  if (personsObj[person.name] == undefined) {
    personsObj[person.name] = person.age
  } else {
    personsObj[person.name] = Math.max(person.age, personsObj[person.name])
  }
})
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(personsObj)) {
  mxPersons.push({
    name: key,
    age: value
  })
}

console.log(mxPersons)
```

Answer (score 0):

The oldest people per name can be obtained by first grouping all people based on their name, then take the oldest person of each group.

This answer does introduce two helper functions `groupBy` and `maxBy`, which add some overhead but are really usefull in general.

```js
const people = [
  { name: 'Joe',  age: 20 },
  { name: 'Alex', age: 24 },  
  { name: 'Joe',  age: 34 },  
  { name: 'Bob',  age: 19 },  
  { name: 'Alex', age: 56 },
];

const oldestPeople = Array
  .from(groupBy(people, person => person.name).values())
  .map(people => maxBy(people, person => person.age));

console.log(oldestPeople);

function groupBy(iterable, fn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = fn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}

function maxBy(iterable, fn) {
  let max, maxValue;
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const itemValue = fn(item);
    if (itemValue <= maxValue) continue;
    [max, maxValue] = [item, itemValue];
  }
  return max;
}
```